# Kohana ORM, define fields in the model

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana

I am learning about ORM. I studied [Jelly](http://jelly.jonathan-geiger.com/) and now I'm testing the Kohana's built in ORM module.
As I see the ORM model is quering:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `table_name`
```

every time you instantiate an ORM model.
For example:

for

```
$user = ORM::factory('user');
```

ORM is quering:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `users`
```

Is there a way to define this table columns/model properties in my model, so ORM don't have to make a db query to obtain them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, studying the ORM's source code :)

You can set:

```
protected $_table_columns;
```